# How to upload an image to a github repository from a Flask app?

Tags: python, image, flask, github, github-api

I would like to use Github to host some user uploaded images and am using the Github api in a flask app to attempt this. The api requires that images are base 64 encoded. I want to see the actual image uploaded to Github, but instead I see the raw code.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTykF.png)

[Result in Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vNLY.png)

Comment: It's better to put your code as text between code tags in the question instead of as an image. Makes it easier to work with.